# Complicated Group SQL Query

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

here is my query and result;

```
select 
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0) as Date, 
Stores.Name StoreName, 
SUM(PosCash + PosCredit + PosBillCash + PosBillCredit) as Revenue  
from StoreRevenue
inner join Stores on Stores.ID = StoreRevenue.StoreID
group by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0), Stores.Name
```

result : http://prntscr.com/zaele

I want to create a table (result) that must be group by date and store names.

```
Date, Avcılar Mağaza, Ataşehir Mağaza
2013-03-04, 150, 200
2013-03-05, 200, 250
2013-03-06, 300, 150
```

rows of sub-group (these ones: 2013-03-04, 150, 200) are date and incomes of each stores 
I want to get that kind of result
I have also tried "pivot" in sql but It doesnt work for me

sorry for my english. -Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` function to transform the data from rows to columns:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0) as Date, 
    Stores.Name StoreName, 
    (PosCash + PosCredit + PosBillCash + PosBillCredit) as Revenue  
  from StoreRevenue
  inner join Stores 
    on Stores.ID = StoreRevenue.StoreID
) d
pivot
(
  sum(Revenue)
  for StoreName in ([Avcılar Mağaza], [Ataşehir Mağaza]..)
) piv;
```

Or you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE`:

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0) as Date,
  sum(case when Stores.Name = 'Avcılar Mağaza' 
      then PosCash + PosCredit + PosBillCash + PosBillCredit end) as [Avcılar Mağaza],
  sum(case when Stores.Name = 'Ataşehir Mağaza' 
      then PosCash + PosCredit + PosBillCash + PosBillCredit end) as [Ataşehir Mağaza]
from StoreRevenue
inner join Stores 
  on Stores.ID = StoreRevenue.StoreID
group by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0)
```

If you have an unknown number fo stores, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from Stores
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select 
                  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0) as Date, 
                  Stores.Name StoreName, 
                  (PosCash + PosCredit + PosBillCash + PosBillCredit) as Revenue  
                from StoreRevenue
                inner join Stores 
                  on Stores.ID = StoreRevenue.StoreID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Revenue)
                for StoreName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: how it can be dynamic store names?

Comment: @user2107255 Yes you can use dynamic SQL if the store names are unknown.  See my edit

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    select 
      DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PostDate), 0) as Date, 
      Stores.Name StoreName, 
      PosCash + PosCredit + PosBillCash + PosBillCredit as Revenue  
    from StoreRevenue
    inner join Stores on Stores.ID = StoreRevenue.StoreID
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS c
PIVOT
(
   SUM(Revenue)
   FOR StoreName IN ([Avcılar Mağaza],  [Ataşehir Mağaza], ...)
) AS p
```

Comment: FYI, you actually don't need the inner `sum()`, you can just use add the columns in the inner query and then the `sum` on the pivot

Comment: Thanks ! prntscr.com/zah7v here is my result, but can we dynamic store names ? just add exist store names as column some kind like that ?

Comment: @user2107255 bluefeet add a dynamic version in his answer, see it.